# What are Root objects with multiple polynomials?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

In Mathematica 9 a new flavor of `Root` object with multiple polynomials was introduced. For example,

```
Root[{327680000000000000 - 1280000000 #1^8 + #1^16 &, #1 + 25 #2 + 25 #2^5 &}, {7, 3}]
```

I've read the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Root.html#) several times, but still do not have a clear understanding of what these expressions mean, or what advantage they have over the older syntax with a single polynomial. Any advice or explanation are welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's read what the docs say:

> Root[{$f_1, f_2 ,\ldots$}, {$k_1, k_2 ,\ldots$}] represents the last coordinate of the exact vector {$a_1, a_2, \ldots$} such that $a_i$ is the $k_i$th root of the polynomial equation $f_i(a_1, \ldots, a_{i-1}, x)=0$.

This, though a bit confusing, is a pretty accurate and straightforward description.  Let's assume two functions ($f_1$ and $f_2$), and substitute $i=1$ into the description.  Then we can read

> ... such that $a_1$ is the $k_1$th root of the polynomial equation $f_1(x)=0$.

With your example, this means that

```
f1 = 327680000000000000 - 1280000000 #1^8 + #1^16 &
f2 = #1 + 25 #2 + 25 #2^5 &

k1 = 7;
k2 = 3;
```

and

```
a1 = Root[f1, k1] // N
(* ==> -8.28089 - 8.28089 I *)
```

Now put in $i=2$, and read the description again:

> Root[{$f_1, f_2$}, {$k_1, k_2$}] represents $a_2$ such that $a_2$ is the $k_2$th root of the polynomial equation $f_2(a_1, x) = 0$.

So let's do

```
a2 = Root[f2[a1, #] &, k2]

(* ==> 0.353233 + 0.353233 I *)
```

This is indeed the numerical value of your `Root` object:

```
N@Root[{f1, f2}, {7, 3}]

(* ==> 0.353233 + 0.353233 I *)
```

I hope this clarifies the definition of the multi-polynomial `Root` objects.

---

Now why would they introduce this?  I don't know. I always assumed that `Root` is not meant for end users to construct directly.  It's simply a representation of algebraic numbers that Mathematica's algorithms can work efficiently with.  I assume that some algorithms in version 9 can work better with this type of `Root` object than with the single-polynomial ones.

You can always convert these to a single-polynomial `Root` object using `RootReduce`:

```
RootReduce@Root[{f1, f2}, {7, 3}] 

(* ==>

Root[268435456 - 160000000000 #1^8 - 1280000000000 #1^12 + 
   14593486328125 #1^16 + 296215781250000 #1^20 + 
   2277618359375000 #1^24 + 10672192343750000 #1^28 + 
   34709265117187500 #1^32 + 83311708281250000 #1^36 + 
   152740318515625000 #1^40 + 218200683593750000 #1^44 + 
   245475769042968750 #1^48 + 218200683593750000 #1^52 + 
   152740478515625000 #1^56 + 83312988281250000 #1^60 + 
   34713745117187500 #1^64 + 10681152343750000 #1^68 + 
   2288818359375000 #1^72 + 305175781250000 #1^76 + 
   19073486328125 #1^80 &, 46]

*)
```

Or just use `N` on them to get a numerical approximation.

Answer (score 4):

First consider :

```
Root[327680000000000000 - 1280000000 #1^8 + #1^16 &, 7] // ToRadicals // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> (-2 - 2 I) 5^(3/4) (10 - 2 Sqrt[5])^(1/8)
> ```

now substitute `#1` with this number  in `#1 + 25 #2 + 25 #2^5 &` switching `#2` to `#1` and compare with your original `Root` object :

```
Root[(-2 - 2 I) 5^(3/4) (10 - 2 Sqrt[5])^(1/8) + 25 #1 + 25 #1^5 &, 3] ==  
Root[{327680000000000000 - 1280000000 #1^8 + #1^16 &, #1 + 25 #2 + 25 #2^5 &}, {7, 3}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Now it appears quite obvious what the updated `Root` object is supposed to represent and the documentation makes no more confusion.
For the sake of simplicity let's repeat the above procedure for another simpler example of a `Root` object taking it from documentation:

```
Root[#1^2 - 3 &, 1]
```

> ```
> -Sqrt[3]
> ```

```
 Root[#1^2 + Sqrt[3] - 5 &, 2]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[5 - Sqrt[3]]
> ```

i.e. it is the same as

```
Root[{#1^2 - 3 &, #2^2 - #1 - 5 &}, {1, 2}]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[5 - Sqrt[3]]
> ```

i.e. we have

```
Root[#1^2 - Root[#1^2 - 3 &, 1] - 5 &, 2] == Root[{#1^2 - 3 &, #2^2 - #1 - 5 &}, {1, 2}]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

To conclude: this new capability of `Root` allows for much simpler representation (we needn't  nest many `Root` objects) of algebraic numbers (roots of univariate polynomials of rational coefficients)   and provides quite terse notation of even complicated algebraic objects.

Answer (score 2):

To give a vague analogy instead of the precise examples given above.

One could think of the equations in the multidimensional version of `Root` as a (lower) triangular system of equations where each equation is a polynomial with  coefficients in the roots of the proceeding equations. Which of the roots are taken as coefficients is specified by the indices.

In the linear case this is exactly an lower triangular linear system of equations, where each equation has exactly on solution.

Is there a more abstract, unifying way to think of this using, say, Groebner Bases? I wonder.

Comment: Yes, this multidimensional root object is (I believe) the "rootified" form corresponding to a lexicographic Groebner basis.