# Finding real roots for an eigth-degree polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, functions

The context for this problem is identical to my first [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57763/solving-l-frac32-sqrt4-pi-2-a2w2-frac-sqrt5-w-sqrt4-pi-2-a). Unfortunately my previous result for $L$ was inexact since it was a relatively simple approximation. This time I have managed to produce a very convincing approximation for $L$. Alike last time, solving for $W$ provides the $n$th solution if you find the $n$th root of a specific [octive] polynomial:

$96x^8-192Lx^7+(768π^2 A^2+128L^2 ) x^6+(-64L^3-640A^2 π^2 L) x^5+(2655π^4 A^4-640L^2 π^2 A^2+32L^4 ) x^4+(384A^2 L^3 π^2-578A^4 Lπ^4 ) x^3+(4476π^6 A^6-2760L^2 π^4 A^4+128L^4 π^2 A^2 ) x^2+(456A^6 Lπ^6-278A^4 L^3 π^4 )x+(3136π^8 A^8-3700L^2 π^6 A^6+1089L^4 π^4 A^4 )=0$

Since my investigation is based on the assumption that there is only one value for $W$, given the values of $A$ and $L$, ergo there should only be two real roots (one should be the positive value for $W$ and the other should be the negative value for $W$.)

My question is, can you find the positive real root for the eight order polynomial above?

Comment: Do you think it has only two Real roots for any `{L, A}`?

Comment: Yes, [I'm not sure if this matters but] provided {L,A}>0

Comment: Might want to provide actual code.

Comment: Solve[l= (√(4 π^2 A^2+W^2 )+W)/2 ((3(√(4 π^2 A^2+W^2 )-W)^2)/(√(4 π^2 A^2+W^2 )+W)(10√(4 π^2 A^2+W^2 )+10 W+√(√(4 π^2 A^2+W^2 )^2 W^2+14 √(4 π^2 A^2+W^2 ) W)) +1), W]

Comment: 96 x^8 - 192 L  x^7 + (768 \[Pi]^2 A^2 + 128 L^2) x^6 + (-64 L^3 - 
    640 A^2 \[Pi]^2 L) x^5 + (2655 \[Pi]^4 A^4 - 
    640 L^2 \[Pi]^2 A^2 + 32 L^4) x^4 + (384 A^2 L^3 \[Pi]^2 - 
    578 A^4 L \[Pi]^4) x^3 + (4476 \[Pi]^6 A^6 - 
    2760 L^2 \[Pi]^4 A^4 + 
    128 L^4 \[Pi]^2 A^2) x^2 + (456 A^6 L \[Pi]^6 - 
    278 A^4 L^3 \[Pi]^4) x + (3136 \[Pi]^8 A^8 - 
   3700 L^2 \[Pi]^6 A^6 + 1089 L^4 \[Pi]^4 A^4)

Answer (score 3):

Let's define a polynomial `p` of one variable `x` depending on two parameters `A` and `L`:

```
p[x_, A_, L_] := 
    96 x^8 − 192 L x^7 + (768 π^2 A^2 + 128 L^2) x^6 
    + (−64 L^3 − 640 A^2 π^2 L) x^5 + (2655 π^4 A^4 − 640 L^2 π^2 A^2 + 32 L^4) x^4 
    + (384 A^2 L^3 π^2 − 578 A^4 L π^4) x^3 
    + (4476 π^6 A^6 − 2760 L^2 π^4 A^4 + 128 L^4 π^2 A^2) x^2 
    + (456 A^6 L π^6 − 278 A^4 L^3 π^4) x 
    + (3136 π^8 A^8 − 3700 L^2 π^6 A^6 + 1089 L^4  π^4 A^4)
```

An appropriate tool for finding positive solutions is `Solve` (one can use `Reduce` also) with the `MaxExtraConditions -> All` option,  moreover we need the assumption `x > 0` and aditionally domain specification `Reals`,  otherwise `A` and `L` might be complex in general, making the task too involved.
So we have:

```
TraditionalForm[ sol = Solve[ p[x, A, L] == 0 && x > 0, x, Reals, 
                              MaxExtraConditions -> All]]
```

[image]

There are three positive real solutions under quite involved conditions ( the second arguments of `ConditionalExpression`), however the first solution is in a zero measure subset of variable space `A , L` thus in fact generically there are only two positive solutions.
 We can verify that the conditions are not satisfied e.g. for `A == 1 && L ==1`, e.g.

```
Simplify[ sol, A == 1 && L == 1]
```

> ```
>  {{x -> Undefined}, {x -> Undefined}, {x -> Undefined}}
> ```

Comment: Does this just proves that there are two positive real roots? How can I find these roots as a f[A,L]?

Comment: @J.D'Almbert I updated my answer. `Root`'s are symbolic representations of exact solutions, under specific conditions one might apply `ToRadicals` to `Root` objects finding solutions in terms of radicals but in general you cannot expect such solutions because it is mathematically impossible to find solutions in terms of radicals for polynomials of order higher than $4$.

Comment: It is important to add that L>>A, e.g. when W=3 and A=2, L=8.7532759347618317962647585592473591641754313583030763

Comment: What is $W$?. Edit your question and make it clear since I'm not sure what you really want if my answer does not satisfy you needs.

Comment: When you simplify "sol" could you make A=2 and L=8.7532759347618317962647585592473591641754313583030763

Comment: `Solve[p[x, 2, 8.753275] == 0 && x > 0, x, Reals]` returns two solutions `{{x -> 2.01469}, {x -> 3.00001}}`.

Comment: Ok so that means the only solution I'm concerned with is the second one. Now, is it possible to represent this solution as just a f[A,L]?

Comment: I have done it in the answer, `Root` objects represetns solutions in terms of `A` and `L`, if you apply `N` you will find numerical approximation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16973/discussion-between-j-dalmbert-and-artes).