# Extract common subexpressions from expressions

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I am trying to evaluate multiple independent expressions with common parts. I would like *Mathematica* to somehow give me this common parts. It's probably not so clear, so let me give you an example.

Let's say I want to compute both of those expressions:

```
x0 = (-b + Sqrt[b²-4ac])/(2a)
x1 = (-b - Sqrt[b²-4ac])/(2a)
```

`a`, `b` and `c` are three scalars but I don't know their values yet.

What I would like is *Mathematica* telling me to define:

```
delta = Sqrt[b²-4ac]
```

and then I can get:

```
x0 = (-b + delta)/(2a)
x1 = (-b - delta)/(2a)
```

Of course this example is easy and can be done manually just by looking at it. But the case I am trying to solve is much more complex in size and cannot be easily done manually.

Here is a concrete example:

```
t = (-a02 a11 b0+a01 a12 b0+a01 a02 b1-a00 a12 b1-a01^2 b2+a00 a11 b2)/
      (a02^2 a11-2 a01 a02 a12+a01^2 a22+a00 (a12^2-a11 a22))
u = (-a12^2 b0+a11 a22 b0+a02 a12 b1-a01 a22 b1-a02 a11 b2+a01 a12 b2)/
      (a02^2 a11-2 a01 a02 a12+a01^2 a22+a00 (a12^2-a11 a22))
v = (a02 a12 b0-a01 a22 b0-a02^2 b1+a00 a22 b1+a01 a02 b2-a00 a12 b2)/
      (a02^2 a11-2 a01 a02 a12+a00 a12^2+a01^2 a22-a00 a11 a22)
```

There are clearly some common parts here and there (of course the denominator). I'd like *Mathematica* to tell me to declare a few intermediate (smaller) expressions to compute the final t,u and v.

Even better would be if it could for example detect that the denominator is the determinant of a 3x3 matrix and tell me that. But maybe this is too difficult. :-)

Comment: [Welcome to Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour), Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as now is hard to understand. Particularly, include a minimum example of the code you are working on that shows the problem and an example of the desired output.

Comment: Thanks @Sektor for the edit. I'm still failing to understand what is the original function from which to get the parts. If its a polynomial, then the OP may use `Coefficient` or `CoefficientList`.

Comment: Something like this,for starters `candidates = Select[Intersection[Level[x0, Infinity], Level[x1, Infinity]], 
 Depth@# > 3 &]`. 
 
But the important thing (I suppose) is the cost of the calc. Impossible to foresee using algebra only

Comment: Also, take a look at **Experimental`OptimizeExpression[{x0, x1}]**

Comment: I took @bel's suggestion to an extreme [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57763/solving-l-frac32-sqrt4-pi-2-a2w2-frac-sqrt5-w-sqrt4-pi-2-a/58985#58985).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Indeed you have :) +1

Comment: OptimizeExpression is pretty nice thank you!

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2885/862) from Leonid

Answer (score 3):

```
x0 = (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 ac])/(2 a);
x1 = (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 ac])/(2 a);

delta = Sqrt[b^2 - 4 ac];

expr = {x0, x1} /. delta -> HoldForm[delta]
```

[image]

```
expr // ReleaseHold
```

[image]

Comment: Replacing is easy when I know the common parts. But I want Mathematica to tell me that I should define a variable equals to Sqrt[b^2-4ac].

Comment: Quote from @belisarius comment:" ... Impossible to foresee using algebra only." Using his comment you can see the common parts but then, again, you have to make your choice.