# How can I simplify a super long expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I am a brand new to using Mathematica, and currently using it for my thesis.

Essentially I have a really long expression made up of lots of parameters.

[image: that looks like this]

I am trying to reduce the size of the expression to something a lot smaller.

Just wondering if anyone had any ideas/tips to help me out.

Comment: This probably should be done along the way that generated that expression. What code generated it?

Comment: So I defined a pretty convoluted 4x4 matrix (m) and super simple vector (Y). Then used the commands   c = Inverse[m].Y    --> c1 = c[[1]]

Comment: Your formulation is not clear: the Normalize command of Mathematica is applicable to vectors and complex numbers only. Please refine your question.

Comment: To get concrete answers, please ask a concrete question. Right now your question is so abstract that the answers will be equally abstract: try `FullSimplify`, `Simplify`, `PowerExpand` etc. possibly with assumptions?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: An outside chance of being related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58985/4999

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Here it's considered helpful to show your own efforts and share your code in a **[well formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. This [question in Meta](https://wolfr.am/v57TjMS9) could be useful.

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because it's not clear what you need. To avoid or revert the Hold you can [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and make it specific, well-structured and easy to understand. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might help to be familiar with how expressions are structured in the Wolfram Language. Try reading through some of the tutorials [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExpressionsOverview.html), particularly [this one](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExpressionsAsTrees.html) about expressions as trees and then [this one](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html) about extracting certain levels of these trees.

It looks like your expression has a lot of smaller repeating subexpressions. As far as I know there isn't a great way to deal with simplifying such expressions built into the language; one that would extract these repeating subexpressions, replacing their instances in the original expression with some unique variable and then annotating the whole thing with maybe an `Inactive[With]` to mimic the "where x = ..." often seen in mathematical literature.

One thing you can do to approximate this feature is to enumerate all of the subexpressions that appear in your expression and see which ones appear most often, then do a simple `ReplaceAll`. For example, if you have an expression like the following

[image: step response]

assigned to a symbol called `expr`, I could do the following

`Level[expr, -5] // Tally // MaximalBy[Last]`

[image: common subexpression]

to find which subexpression (subtree) with height of at least 5 occurs most often. Assigning this subexpression to `subexpr` and then using `ReplaceAll` you get

`expr /. subexpr -> x`

[image: simplified]

which is clearly a much smaller and more manageable expression.

While not a comprehensive answer, hopefully this gives you some additional avenues to explore beyond what other users have suggested.