# Find function inverse

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I'm trying to find the inverse of a function:

```
(30*x^2 (1 - x)^2) (* where 0<x<1 *)
```

I tried all the following options:

1.

```
InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[30*#1^2 (1 - #1)^2, 0 < #1 < 1] &]
```

2.

```
f = Function[30*#^2 (1 - #)^2] &

g = InverseFunction[f]
```

3.

```
g[x_] = 30*x^2 (1 - x)^2

sol = Solve[y == x^2 &&  0 < x < 1, x]

D[x /. sol[[1]], y]
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Solve` also works

```
Solve[y == 30 x^2 (1 - x)^2 && 0 < x < 1, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-y + 30 #1^2 - 60 #1^3 + 30 #1^4 &, 2], 0 < y < 15/8]}, 
>  {x -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-y + 30 #1^2 - 60 #1^3 + 30 #1^4 &, 3], 0 < y < 15/8]}}
> ```

Use `ToRadicals` to get it in a nice looking form.

Comment: why does mathematica convert x into #1 ?

Comment: @user19754 That's not really what's happening here.  Please read this: [(24945)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24945/121) as well as the documentation for `Root`.

Answer (score 8):

Your second approach is nearly correct. Modify it like so.

```
f = 30*#^2 (1 - #)^2 &;
g = InverseFunction[f]
```

> ```
> 1/30 (15 - Sqrt[15] Sqrt[15 - 2 Sqrt[30] Sqrt[#1]]) &
> ```

```
Plot[f[g[x]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Hm... I overlooked that mistake. +1

Comment: this gives an error "InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses. "

Comment: @user19754 Right.  See my answer for a different treatment.

Comment: @user19754. It's not an error message. It's a warning. In the domain `{0, 1}`, the `g` is fine. In the domain x < 0, it is not valid. You can turn it off with `Quiet`.

Comment: @m_goldberg Are you saying that one of the branches I show is invalid or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. In the domain {0,1}, specified by the OP, either brach will work. The way the question is posed, makes me think the OP would be satisfied by any functional form that works in his domain, and and is not interested in the complete set.

Answer (score 6):

[`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) appears to provide useful information:

```
Reduce[{(30*x^2 (1 - x)^2) == y, 0 < x < 1}, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> (0 < y < 15/8 && (x == Root[-y + 30 #1^2 - 60 #1^3 + 30 #1^4 &, 2] || 
>      x == Root[-y + 30 #1^2 - 60 #1^3 + 30 #1^4 &, 3])) || (y == 15/8 && x == 1/2)
> ```

[`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToRadicals.html) can be used to put this into a more familiar form.

```
% // ToRadicals
```

> ```
> (0 < y < 15/8 && (x == 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[15 - 2 Sqrt[30] Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[15]) || 
>      x == 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[15 + 2 Sqrt[30] Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[15]))) || (y == 15/8 && x == 1/2)
> ```

Branches:

```
Plot[
 {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[15 - 2 Sqrt[30] Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[15]), 
  1/2 (1 - Sqrt[15 + 2 Sqrt[30] Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[15])},
 {y, 0, 15/8}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this option! For some reason, mine output is all in decimals, I wonder if I can reset it globally to output fractions

Comment: never mind, it works great!

Answer (score 6):

A good comprehensive answer should explain why `InverseFunction` "didn't work", however there's been no  explanation so far. 
A unique inverse function can be found in a region if there its jacobian is nondegenerate, i.e. its determinant doesn't vanish ([Inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)) . For one - variable function it means that the derivative doesn't vanish.

```
Reduce[ D[ 30 #1^2 (1 - #1)^2 &[x], x] != 0, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> x < 0 || 0 < x < 1/2 || 1/2 < x < 1 || x > 1
> ```

Now taking any of the specified ranges `InverseFunction` works expectedly:

```
InverseFunction[ ConditionalExpression[30*#1^2 (1 - #1)^2, 0 < #1 < 1/2] &][y]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[Root[-y + 30 #1^2 - 60 #1^3 + 30 #1^4 &, 2], 0 < y < 15/8]
> ```

```
InverseFunction[ ConditionalExpression[30*#1^2 (1 - #1)^2, 1/2 < #1 < 1] &][y]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[Root[-y + 30 #1^2 - 60 #1^3 + 30 #1^4 &, 3], 0 < y < 15/8]
> ```

so depending on the region inverse  function might be any of `Root[-y + 30 #1^2 - 60 #1^3 + 30 #1^4 &, k]` for $k=1\ldots4$.

Invertibility of the given function is restrected to appropriate regions, this can be easily seen from the following plot

```
Plot[ 30 #1^2 (1 - #1)^2 &[x], {x, -1/4, 5/4}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
      Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[0.008], Line[{{-1/2, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
                 Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {1/2, 0}}], 
                 Darker @ Green, Line[{{1/2, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
                 Darker @ Magenta, Line[{{1, 0}, {3/2, 0}}], 
                 Red, Dashed, Line[{{{0, 3}, {0, -1}}, {{1/2, 3}, {1/2, -1}}, 
                                   {{1, 3}, {1, -1}}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Artes, this is a great explanation. How do we deal with functions such as the one given in this question where there are multiple monotone regions? For example y=x^2 is monotone on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0, \infty)$ . Is it possible for mathematica to recognize that and give two answers like -sqrt(y) for the first region and  and sqrt(y) for the second?

Comment: @user19754 Great? No upvotes so far... `Reduce[y == x^2, x, Reals]` yields `y >= 0 && (x == -Sqrt[y] || x == Sqrt[y])`. Perhaps also `FunctionDomain[InverseFunction[#^2 &][x], x]` could be useful however this should be more a bit precise question.

Comment: Artes, Reduce[y == x^2 && x > -1 && x < 1, x, Reals] works, giving (0 < y < 1 && (x == -Sqrt[y] || x == Sqrt[y]), but it does not give us the information that for  -Sqrt[y] x must be from -1 to 0 and for the other one, from 0 to 1. I'm sorry if my question is confusing

Answer (score 1):

```
purify[f_, x_] := Function @@ {f /. x -> #}

fun = 30*x^2 (1 - x)^2;

inv = InverseFunction[purify[fun, x]][x] // Quiet
```

[image]

```
LogPlot[{fun, inv}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for a nice option. It does not output the range for y though.